# git clone doesn't work with HTTPS after creating Personal Access Token (PAT)

Tags: git, github, ssh, https, git-bash

So far I was using a password for for authentication when working with git bash and was recently notified about the deprecation of such authentication and instructed to create a PAT for authentication.

I followed the approach and created a PAT successfully. I then used the credential helper to store my new credentials (`$ git config --global credential.helper wincred`).

Prior to all of the above, I also updated the git bash for windows, so now I have the version  `2.32.0.windows.1`.

After doing all this, I can no longer clone the repositories using the HTTPS. What is weird is that the repository I am trying to clone is actually using the HTTPS remote URL - I checked this with:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/***/****.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/***/****.git (push)
```

(I used the asterisk symbols to hide the personal details)

Another weird thing is that when cloning the repo from the terminal (linux terminal for win), it works without problems.

Does anyone have any solutions or knows where the problem is? I don't have much experience and I tried what seemed reasonable to me.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Just to be clearer, I'm not getting any error messages when trying to use 'git clone' with HTTPS - the process starts but never seems to finish, it just hangs there without coming to a stop.

Also, 'git clone' works with SSH for me, but what I would like to get as an answer is how I could make it work with HTTPS (as it was before).

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the exact error message you get as a text block?  Also, when you entered your credentials, did you enter your username for the username and your PAT for the password?

Comment: So I'm not getting an error message, but the git clone using HTTPS just hangs and seems to run forever. I was actually never asked to enter my credentials by git bash since I generated the token.

Comment: You'll probably want to run the clone as  `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://...` to see more about what's going on.  That should tell you if the problem is the credential helper hanging, and HTTP problem, or something else.

Comment: @bk2204 Okay, I just did that, but due to my lack of experience, I'm not sure I understand what the output is telling me. Could I somehow send it to you (it's quite lengthy)?

Comment: Git version `2.32.0.windows.1` seems to tickle some kind of Windows bug here. Many have reported this same problem; downgrading to Git 2.30 gets around it.

Answer (score 0):

`wincred` is no longer what you want as Git credential manager helper on Windows (10 at least) and [Git for Windows 2.32+](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

```
git config --global credential.helper manager-core
```

Then:

- make sure that `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core` is in your %PATH%
- double-check what is stored in the Windows Credential Manager

That is:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https"|git-credential-manager get
```

If you see the wrong password, remove it with

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https"|git-credential-manager erase
```

Repeat the erase command until you see a popup (do not enter your credentials)

Then do a `git ls-remote https://github.com/***/****.git`, and enter your credentials to store them.